# Dynamically extend CakePHP form without disabling SecurityComponent

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a CakePHP (2.4) form I am trying to dynamically add fields to using Javascript. However, SecurityComponent is rightfully blackholing when I try to POST my form with the extra fields, and I'd like to get around that.

I know you can do `$this->Form->unlockField('Field.0.value');` in order to unlock a specific field so Security doesn't validate it, however I'd like to be building my app in the most secure, standards-compliant manner possible. What would the CakePHP best practice for this be, barring disabling Security?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have your cake and eat it too :)  Security component's job is to prevent form manipulation (among other things). So if you want to dynamically add fields to your form using JavaScript, you will have to specify the "unlocked fields" or disable security component for that page.

Comment: So if I want to unlock fields I have to explicitly unlock each one, I can't do a wildcard unlock of all `"Field.*.value"` fields?

Comment: No, wildcards are not supported.